# With-statement with several variables: is there a more readable way to write this?

Tags: python, with-statement, zen-of-python

For example, I need to open two files using one `with` statement. 
And there's also a condition for each of them: to actually open or to use something instead.

In my case, it's whether to open a file specified by name or use stdin/stdout if name is not specified. The problem is that it's too long and complex for single line.

```
with    open(src_name, 'r') if src_name else sys.stdin as src, open(dst_name, 'w') if dst_name else sys.stdout as dst:
    # do something
    pass
```

For the first time, I had something like:

```
with    open(src_name, 'r') if src_name else sys.stdin as src, \
        open(dst_name, 'w') if dst_name else sys.stdout as dst:
    # do something
    pass
```

I personally like this version. For me it looks straightforward, but I need to use spaces to align two lines (and my IDE, PyCharm, warns me about extra spaces). BTW, Is it really critical to use spaces in python to align code?

The other way to align is:

```
with open(src_name, 'r') if src_name else sys.stdin as src, \
     open(dst_name, 'w') if dst_name else sys.stdout as dst:
    # do something
    pass
```

But it seems even worse due to [PEP 8 – indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

And I don't like the "correct" version which is less readable and for the first glance even confusing:

```
with open(src_name, 'r') if src_name else sys.stdin as src, \
        open(dst_name, 'w') if dst_name else sys.stdout as dst:
    # do something
    pass
```

I can nest it in two levels but it is bad according to zen..

So i'm interested if there's a more elegant way to write this?
Or maybe my version is good and I should ignore that warning about spaces.

Comment: Please ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The premise of the question is (kind of) wrong - you never ever ever want to write `with sys.stdin:` or `with sys.stdout:`. You won't be able to use `input()` or `print()` after the `with` statement.

Comment: @Rawing oh, you pointed out an important problem in that code. I didn't think about closing the stdin/stdout and that's something to remember. Thank you, maybe you saved some hours of my life handling future errors due to that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the great uncle bob, author of 'Clean Code' and famed engineer, 'never let the readers of your code scroll sideways', and 'your code should read like well written prose'.

Instead of placing the if statement within the with block, why not separate them.

```
if src_name:
    with open(src_name, 'r') as f:
        pass #do something
else:
    pass # do something else
```

Also, consider using better names for your variables, i.e. instead of `src_name` use `file_path` > makes more sense.

I highly recommend ['Clean Code' by Robert C. Martin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) - it changed my life.

Comment: Now you get duplicated code. A function would work best

Comment: Well, i'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I was just trying to make a point about readability with my code snippet.

Comment: You can also create a function that handles the boolean condition

Comment: That's what I meant by "A function would work best".

Comment: @EytanAvisror Thank you, I got your point. 
And what about my additional question "BTW, Is it really critical to use spaces in python to align code?". 
May be you read it in the book you recommended?

Comment: It depends what you mean by spaces - Indentation is very critical in python. PEP8 is should be looked at as recommended style, many programmers chose to write in different styles - personally I adhere to PEP8, I think it looks great, and works well for code readability.